Cassandra not starting up on Windows 10
I am working on Windows 10 OS and I downloaded apache-cassandra-3.11.16. As requirement I installed Python 2.7 and Java 8.

Inside bin folder's cmd I ran Cassandra and server started without any issues. Inside other cmd I ran cqlsh and it ran perfectly.
I ended my server with Ctrl+C.
When I restarted my pc and tried Cassandra it threw this error:

Now I'm stuck unable to start Cassandra. I tried to unzip Cassandra on different location but it gave same error. Now Cassandra is not starting.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

This message is the reason Cassandra does not start:
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.

There is a check performed in conf/cassandra-env.ps1 to verify that a newer version of Java 8 is installed:
    if ($env:JVM_VERSION.CompareTo("1.8.0") -eq -1 -or [convert]::ToInt32($env:JVM_PATCH_VERSION) -lt 40)
    {
        echo "Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later."
        exit
    }

My guess is that the check fails to find Java 8 because JAVA_HOME is not configured correctly on the machine's environment variables.
As a side note, there has been ongoing issues with running Cassandra on Windows and we decided that it is not good for the project (see the discussion in this thread) so support for Windows was dropped completely (CASSANDRA-16171).
I recommend the following alternatives:

Deploy Cassandra on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2)
Deploy Cassandra in Docker
Deploy Cassandra in a Kubernetes cluster with open-source K8ssandra.io

Otherwise if you just want to learn how to build apps on Cassandra, Astra DB has a free tier where you can launch a cluster in about 60 seconds with no credit card required. Cheers!

First, check Cassandra's log files to see if there is more information about the error.
Then, confirm that your port is not occupied by other programs. You can use commands to view the current port usage.netstat -aon
Next, check Cassandra's data directory permissions to make sure that the Cassandra process can write to them.
If none of the above steps resolve the issue, you may want to check out Cassandra's official documentation or community support for more help.

In log folder there are debug file and log file and i checked them both, there isn't any error mentioned.  i had checked port, port is not occupied, data directory permission is also allowed to write but issue presists

I had this issue because I had different versions of java installed on my machine and Cassandra needed a specific version.
I was using Jenv tool to configure my local directory java version as needed but to resolve this issue I need to reset the Environment_path variable with needed java version and this issue got resolved.
